# Вопрос про перемножение

Tags: python, list

Вообщем, не могу сообразить , как написать цикл.

```
symbols = [
    ['x', 'y', 'z'],
    ['a', 'b', 's'],
    ['q', 'z', 't'],
    ['h', 'n', 'm'],
    ]
do_list = [1, 2, 3]
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы подсписки symbols (например `['x', 'y', 'z']`) имел всевозможные комбинации внутри этого списка с компонентами списка do_list в таком формате.

```
combination = [
    [['x', 1], ['y', 1], ['z', 1]],
    [['x', 1], ['y', 1], ['z', 2]],
    [['x', 1], ['y', 1], ['z', 3]],
    [['x', 1], ['y', 2], ['z', 2]],
    ......
    
    ]
```

То есть всевозможные комбинации с тремя константами из списка `do_list`

Или укажите, пожалуйста, направление, в котором нужно искать.
Спасибо!

Comment: Не дочитал. Сейчас пример приведу

Comment: Мне это очень `tensorflow` напоминает. Походу, где-то там решение.

Comment: Хз. Через `itertools` делаем все возможные комбинации `do_list`, а потом через `zip()` собираем. Ответ ниже

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Родил. Через `itertools` делаем все возможные комбинации `do_list`, а потом через `zip()` собираем в цикле.

```
import itertools

symbols = [
    ['x', 'y', 'z'],
    ['a', 'b', 's'],
    ['q', 'z', 't'],
    ['h', 'n', 'm'],
    ]
do_list = [1, 2, 3]

list_ = [[(c, n) for c, n in zip(s, r)] 
         for s in symbols for r in list(itertools.product(do_list, repeat=len(s)))]

print(*list_, sep='\n')
```

Спасибо *CrazyElf* забыл, что можно из zip() не вытаскивать, а сразу преобразовать:

```
list_ = [list(zip(s, r)) for s in symbols for r in list(itertools.product(do_list, repeat=len(s)))]
```

Вывод:

```
[('x', 1), ('y', 1), ('z', 1)]
[('x', 1), ('y', 1), ('z', 2)]
[('x', 1), ('y', 1), ('z', 3)]
[('x', 1), ('y', 2), ('z', 1)]
[('x', 1), ('y', 2), ('z', 2)]
[('x', 1), ('y', 2), ('z', 3)]
...
[('h', 3), ('n', 3), ('m', 3)]
```

Расшифровываем строку:

```
list_ = [[(c, n) for c, n in zip(s, r)] 
         for s in symbols for r in list(itertools.product(do_list, repeat=len(s)))]
```

Создаем массив с нумерацией от `[[1,1,1], [1,1,2], ... [3,3,3]]`:

```
list(itertools.product(do_list, repeat=len(s)))
```

Далее в цикле извлекаем строки из массива `[[x, y, z], ...]`, параллельно пуская внутренний цикл по массиву `list(itertools...` с извлечением строк `[1,1,1]...[3,3,3]`.

```
for s in symbols for r in list(itertools.product(do_list, repeat=len(s)))
```

На выходе имеем переменные `s = [x, y, z] и т.д.` и `r = [1,1,1] и т.д.`. Их объединяем через `zip(s, r)` и преобразуем в список:

```
list(zip(s, r)) for s in symbols for r in list(itertools.product(do_list, repeat=len(s)))
```

И в конце все это собирается в один большой список:

```
[list(zip(s, r)) for s in symbols for r in list(itertools.product(do_list, repeat=len(s))))]
```

Comment: Блин. просто ума у тебя палата! Спасибо, бро!

Comment: Бро, а ты не мог бы помочь расшифровать строчку?

Comment: `list_ = [[(c, n) for c, n in zip(s, r)] 
         for s in symbols for r in list(itertools.product(do_list, repeat=len(s)))]`

Comment: Добавил пояснения в ответ

Comment: У меня проблема.

Comment: По какой -то непонятной причине `('y', 2)` не итерируется на y и 2

Comment: Там же должен быть вложенный список. `('y', 2)`. Сейчас почитаю, что вы написали и попробую сам исправить

Comment: Кстати, первый `for` вроде и не нужен, достаточно написать `list(zip(s, r))`

Comment: Точно) Спасибо большое)

Comment: А c `do_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` будет работать?

Comment: Будет работать, даже если у Вас символьные строки будут разной длины `['x', 'y', 'z', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 's'], ...]`